# Why is Definition Query not returning any records?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, definition-query

I am currently working on a mapping project and only need 8 tenements out of many to appear. I have gone into the query builder to complete this and unfortunately it will not work. Into the builder a put Tenement = 'E59/1002' AND Tenement = 'E59/1421'. It verifies but no records are found. I am not sure why this is happening as this method has always worked for me before when i need to select multiple tenements.

Any help?

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is change AND to OR.  Because AND is a valid logical operator the validation passes. So technically the query is correct, it just will not return any records.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the IN (includes). Like...
Tenement IN ('E59/1002', 'E59/1421')
Tenement NOT IN ('E60/1002', 'E60/1421')